# How to transfer data between two devices using WIFI-Direct?

Tags: android, sockets, wifip2p

I want to write a chat application which uses WIFI-Direct only and there are no internet or routers at all.

I've created a Wi-Fi P2P Application which can see other devices with enabled WIFI-Direct. The android guides are here : [Wi-Fi Peer-to-Peer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)

Two devices connects to each other with WIFI-Direct and the specifications of connected device will be shown in my app.

At this point, I don't know what is the best way to transfer data between this two devices? Socket programming or what else ways are there to do this?

For Socket programming paradigm, the data flow will be from client to server only, how to transfer data in both directions?

Comment: You are wrong. As soon as there is connection the data can flow in both directions.

Comment: I don't understand how? Can you explain? The given example in android guide was too brief, I can't get that.

Comment: It is so easy to find code for a server and code for a client. Hundreds of examples in net. A hundred times discussed here. A thousand times posting data to an http server and receiving a result has been treated here. So i wonder why you doubt. Nearly every day someone posts such a problem. Just read pages taggged 'android'.

Comment: I want an app to be client and server at same time. the examples divide these in two applications. in addition when there is no router, how can I get a device's IP? the IP is needed to transfer data with socket!

Comment: `I want an app to be client and server at same time.` That is possible of course. But now you are talking about something different. We were discussing your remark `the data flow will be from client to server only, how to transfer data in both directions?` You have heard my opinion. I did not hear that agree. Or you confirmed.